# Doctrine relationship disappears after persist and flush

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine

I have a many to one relationship between an entity that records notes and an entity that has the user making the comments. i.e. one user can make many comments.

The comments display fine when viewing the page for the first time, $note->employee->user gets the user name from the employee table based on the many to one relationship with the notes table.  When a new note is added via posting a form:

```
$activity = new \S2\Entity\Crmnotes;
$activity->solicitorid = $solicitorid;
$activity->note = $activityDescription;
$activity->employeeid = 2;
$activity->type = $activityType;
$this->_em->persist($activity);
$this->_em->flush();
```

The page then will display the data from the notes entity but not from any of its relationships, i.e. $notes->note, $notes->type display but $notes->employee->user causes a Trying to get property of non-object error.

When the page is next visited, all the data is then displayed fine as usual.

**EDIT**

As an additional point the datetime object $note->lastmodified also fails to display after the insert of the record.  I get the error of Call to a member function format() on a non-object, when I try to format the date e.g. $note->lastmodified->format('d/m/Y H:i');

**EDIT**
Yes, it is doctrine 2.
As requested:

```
namespace S2\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Crmnotes
 *
 * @Table(name="crmnotes")
 * @Entity
 */
class Crmnotes extends \S2_Doctrine_Entity
{
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="S2\Entity\Tblsolicitor", inversedBy="crmnotes")
 * @JoinColumn(name="SolicitorID", referencedColumnName="SolicitorID")
 * 
 */
 private $solicitor;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(cascade={"persist"}, targetEntity="S2\Entity\Tblemployees", inversedBy="crmnotes")
 * @JoinColumn(name="EmployeeID", referencedColumnName="EmployeeID")
 * 
 */
 private $employee;

/**
 * @var integer $notesid
 *
 * @Column(name="notesid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $notesid;

/**
 * @var integer $type
 *
 * @Column(name="type", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var integer $solicitorid
 *
 * @Column(name="SolicitorID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $solicitorid;

/**
 * @var text $note
 *
 * @Column(name="Note", type="text", nullable=false)
 */
private $note;

/**
 * @var integer $employeeid
 *
 * @Column(name="EmployeeID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $employeeid;

/**
 * @var datetime $lastmodified
 *
 * @Column(name="LastModified", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $lastmodified;

public function __get($name) 
{
    if (isset($this->$name)){
        return $this->$name;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function __set($name, $value) 
{
    $this->$name = $value;
}


}
```

**EDIT**

Still no joy when using objects instead of trying to insert foreign key manually:

```
$activity = new \S2\Entity\Crmnotes;
$activity->note = $activityDescription;
$activity->type = $activityType;
$solicitor = $this->_em->getRepository('\S2\Entity\Tblsolicitor')->find($solicitorid);
$solicitor->crmnotes->add($activity);
$activity->solicitor = $solicitor;
$employee = $this->_em->getRepository('\S2\Entity\Tblemployees')->find(2);
$this->view->debug = $solicitor->crmnotes[0]->note;
$employee->crmnotes->add($activity);
$activity->employee = $employee;
$this->_em->persist($activity);
$this->_em->flush();
```

Comment: Is this using Doctrine2? Normally you would use setters and set the entity rather than the ID. In fact, you should never use the foreign key ID directly as doctrine handles all of this for you. Perhaps you could post your entity class.

Comment: There is a shortcut for `$this->_em->getRepository('\S2\Entity\Tblemployees')->find(2)` -> `$this->_em->find('\S2\Entity\Tblemployees', 2);`

Also u could use `$this->_em->getReference('\S2\Entity\Tblemployees', 2);` for better performance  when managing relationships

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
/**
 * @var integer $employeeid
 *
 * @Column(name="EmployeeID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $employeeid;
```

As newer Doctrine complains about it when there is also relationship using same column.

```
* @JoinColumn(name="EmployeeID", referencedColumnName="EmployeeID")
```

maybe references id instead of EmployeeID ?

```
  if (isset($this->$name)){
        return $this->$name;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
```

No need to check it, Doctrine returns null if its empty

I don't see anywhere u set LastModified ?

```
$entity->lastmodified = new \DateTime();
```